# openvz node with only one vps

Tags: centos, virtualization, vps, centos5, openvz

I have an openvz server with 2Gb ram and would like to configure a vps for use all server resources (no swap).

I run:

vzsplit -n 1 -f vps1 -s 0

and have this setup:

Configuration file generated by vzsplit for 1 containers 
 on HN with total amount of physical mem 1998 Mb 
 low memory 1998 Mb, swap size 0 Mb, Max treads 8000 
 Resourse commit level 0:
 Free resource distribution. Any parameters may be 
 Primary parameters

NUMPROC="10230:10230"
AVNUMPROC="5115:5115"
NUMTCPSOCK="10230:10230"
NUMOTHERSOCK="10230:10230"
VMGUARPAGES="294151:9223372036854775807"

Secondary parameters

KMEMSIZE="419090432:460999475"
TCPSNDBUF="97794730:139696810"
TCPRCVBUF="97794730:139696810"
OTHERSOCKBUF="48897365:90799445"
DGRAMRCVBUF="48897365:48897365"
OOMGUARPAGES="294151:9223372036854775807"
PRIVVMPAGES="306951:337646"

Auxiliary parameters

LOCKEDPAGES="20463:20463"
SHMPAGES="30695:30695"
PHYSPAGES="0:9223372036854775807"
NUMFILE="163680:163680"
NUMFLOCK="1000:1100"
NUMPTY="512:512"
NUMSIGINFO="1024:1024"
DCACHESIZE="91533669:94279680"
NUMIPTENT="200:200"
DISKSPACE="203811210:224192332"
DISKINODES="53798327:59178160"
CPUUNITS="139987"

When I start a new vps with this setup the vps run out of memory.

The "free" command show only 1.2 Gb ram.

Are this setup the optimal for my vps ?

Are the memory parameters correct ?

I suspect that vzsplit is generating bad memory settings for my vps.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the amount of memory on the fly, currently you have allocated:
294151 pages (of 4k each), which translates to roughly 1.2GB.

If you want to change this to something closer to 2GB:

```
vzctl set VZID --vmguarpages 524288:9223372036854775807
```

Or just give the VPS all the memory, by not limiting it:

```
vzctl set VZID --vmguarpages 9223372036854775807:9223372036854775807
```

(Replace VZID with the id returned by vzlist -a)